# What are the implications of Russel's paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Daniel J. Velleman's *How To Prove It* there is an exercise which asks us to consider the existence of the set of all sets and its implications:

> Suppose U were the collection of all sets. Note that in particular U is
> a set, so we would have U ∈ U. This is not yet a contradiction; although
> most sets are not elements of themselves, perhaps some sets are elements
> of themselves. But it suggests that the sets in the universe U could be
> split into two categories: the unusual sets that, like U itself, are elements
> of themselves, and the more typical sets that are not. Let R be the set of
> sets in the second category. In other words, R = {A ∈ U | A ∈/ A}. This
> means that for any set A in the universe U, A will be an element of R iff
> A ∈/ A. In other words, we have ∀A ∈ U(A ∈ R ↔ A ∈/ A)
>
> > (a) Show that applying this last fact to the set R itself (in other words,
> > plugging in R for A) leads to a contradiction.

Since $R \in U$, we have that $R \in R ↔ R \notin R$, a contradiction, Russel's famous paradox. We are then asked to reflect on its implications. I used to think that Russel's paradox refuted the existence of a set which contains itself, but it seems to me now that it just refutes the idea that any definable collection is a set, or that one can subdivide any set into any two subsets. [In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046863/how-can-a-set-contain-itself) I found out that sets that contain themselves can exist even in the context of **ZFC**.

I  also can't see how this paradox *proves* that there can't be a set of all sets. I've seen proofs of it based on [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), but once again the paradox  seems to me not to prove the impossibility of the existence of the set of all sets, but the impossibility of the construction of a certain subset of it.

Concluding, is Russel's paradox just an argument against the idea than any definable collection is a set, or is there more profound implications of it I am not aware of?

Comment: That is a profound implication (at least for me). It tells use we cannot simply write $\{ x \ \vert \ \varphi(x) \text{ true} \}$ and be sure we have a set.

Comment: See [Axioms Schema of Specification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545627/is-the-axiom-schema-of-specification-sufficient-for-solving-russells-paradox-i) that replaced [Comprehension Principle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/)

Comment: In ZFC there is no set can contain itself. This is a quite direct consequence of the Axiom of Foundation (or Regularity)

Comment: See also [The Early Development of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/) for motivations (also *several* paradoxes) leading to [Axiomatization of ST](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zermelo-set-theory/#Sep)

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162/why-is-the-set-of-all-sets-a-paradox-in-laymans-terms/909772#909772

Comment: @AsafKaragila Great answer! I had seen that question, but your answer is much more profound than the acepted one.

Comment: Thanks. I had neither the knowledge nor the clarity of thought to write that answer when the question was new (and arguably, I didn't have a user account when the question was just posted either). So answering only a few years after the question was posted means that it's unlikely to be accepted. I'm just glad it helped.

Comment: Certainly the best answers to this question are written by set theorists. Just to provide some variety, from a non-set theorist's perspective, my answer is: "nothing". Axiomatic issues like this simply do not arise in my work and never bother me. I'm quite content blithely assuming bounded comprehension, simply because I ultimately care about "concrete" examples, like, say, sets of polynomials, where it's just plain true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* prove that there is no set of sets in ZFC, where we have as an axiom ([separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) or comprehension) that **if** $y$ is a set and $\phi(x)$ is some predicate with free variable $x$ (ignoring parameters for now) **then** $\{x \in y\mid \phi(x)\}$ is *also* a set. So if $U$ (the set of all sets) existed, so would $\{x \in U\mid x \notin x\}$ and this leads to a contradiction. So $U$ does *not* exist in a system obeying this axiom (like ZFC, which we do assume in almost all of maths).